# POST request to Web server android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post

I am working on an Application which is using the AsyncTask. I am trying to connect to my website, check user login details and return true if user exists and false if not found. Based on the response I will display an error message or load up the relevant screen for the user.

However I am wondering if the below code should be placed in the onClick listener of my login button or in the onPreExecute() method of the AsyncTask?

I call the asyncTask like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            //Call background task
            new HttpTask().execute(url);
        }
    });
```

Does it matter where I call the below code? Should it ideally be in the onPreExecute() method?

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mysite.com/checklogindetails.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", name));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Thanks for any info regarding this guys. It's not a problem as such, it's more a learning curve for me and I'm curious what I should do.

thanks.

Comment: Place that code in the doInBackground method, and I think putting the execute command in the login onclick is where it should be, so that when you click login it grabs the user and pass and then runs the asynctask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTTP code needs to be in the `doInBackground()` method, otherwise it is still running in the main (UI) thread and can cause exceptions on new Android versions (not to mention lockups if your request takes a long time).

Here is an example (note the constructor addition) I decided to keep the pairs inside `doInBackground()`. Since you haven't given us all code, this probably won't work right off the bat.

```
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Boolean>{

  private String name = "", pass= "";
  public LoginTask (String name, String pass )
  {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.pass = pass;
  }
  @Override
  protected Boolean  doInBackground (String...url)
  { 
    boolean good = true;

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url[0]);

    try {
      // Add your data
      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", name));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
      httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

      // Execute HTTP Post Request
      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      good = false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      good = false;
    }
    return good;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute (Boolean result)
  {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result ? "Logged in": "Problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

And you'd call using

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            //Call background task
            new HttpTask("myusername", "mypassword").execute(url);
        }
    });
```

Comment: can I add the namevaluepairs to the httppost object in `onPreExecute()` ? Or does it make a huge difference? When you say http request in `doInBackground()` does that just involve calling this line of code `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost)`?

Comment: @Javacadabra the name value pairs seem to only be data, so I'd say they're safe on be `onPreExecute()`. However `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);` definitely needs to be in `doInBackground()`

Comment: @Javacadabra added an example. I kept the value pairs inside `doInBackground()`, it's not a big deal since I added a constructor. The code doesn't do much (since I used your HTTP request,) but it should compile, so you have some sort of basis/template of how to get everything set up.

Comment: Thank's very much for that! Great answer.